# Force directed Cola layout with Cytoscape similar to Cola example

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js, webcola

I am using cytoscape.js and the cola extension and I am interested in creating a layout [similar to this example](http://marvl.infotech.monash.edu/webcola/examples/disconnected_graphs.html).

There [is an example](http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/2ebdc40f1c2540de6cf0/) of using cola with cytoscape.js on the website, but they do not have this non-overlapping functionality.

I tried the infinite:true option, but it does not appear to work as expected. I am wondering how this is achieved with cytoscape.js and cola.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `infinite: true` parameter as you first tried. You will also want the `fit: false` parameter in order to be able to zoom and pan.

For example:

```
var cy = cytoscape({
    container: $('#cy'),
    elements: /*...*/,
    layout: {
        name: 'cola',
        infinite: true,
        fit: false
    }
});
```

I made a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWEOKw (you need to load in HTTP: I did not find an HTTPS CDN for cola...)

Comment: Thanks so much! So I discovered that the demo I was tweaking, the cola example from the cytoscape.js github repo - is actually using an old version of cytoscape-cola 1.1.1 - and by using the 1.5.0 version that you are using I was able to get the expected results!

Answer (score 1):

Overlap avoidance is a built-in feature of Cola.  Unless you specify particular options that make overlap avoidance impossible, Cola will produce results where the nodes do not overlap.

You can use `nodeSpacing` to specify extra space around the nodes.  Increasing the value makes the nodes more spaced out as the demo shows: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/2ebdc40f1c2540de6cf0/

Comment: I am using the default settings form the cytoscape-cola github repo - Maybe I am not understanding how to achieve the example from cola above. Do I need to bind some event to re-initialize the layout on the movement of my individual nodes? It seems that after the layout has settled, the nodes are able to overlap each other again.

Comment: As the user pushes and pulls the nodes, I would like the surrounding nodes to move out of the way, and conversely be pulled around - none of the examples on cytoscape website show this so I am unsure how it is achieved with the library.